# ¿Cómo setear horas de un arreglo de objetos?

Tags: javascript, json, array, jsonobject

Buen día amigos, tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos

```
  (8) [
     0: {fechas: "2018-11-01", registros: 0}
     1: {fechas: "2018-10-26", registros: 0}
     2: {fechas: "2018-10-27", registros: 0}
     3: {fechas: "2018-10-28", registros: 0}
     4: {fechas: "2018-10-29", registros: 0}
     5: {fechas: "2018-10-30", registros: 0}
     6: {fechas: "2018-10-31", registros: 8}
     7: {fechas: "2018-10-31", registros: 0}]
```

Lo que debo de hacer es que me organicé el arreglo de menor a mayor por fechas y que los que estén repitidos y que estén en cero los elimine, o sea de la siguiente manera:

```
    (7)      [
     0: {fechas: "2018-10-26", registros: 0}
     1: {fechas: "2018-10-27", registros: 0}
     2: {fechas: "2018-10-28", registros: 0}
     3: {fechas: "2018-10-29", registros: 0}
     4: {fechas: "2018-10-30", registros: 0}
     5: {fechas: "2018-10-31", registros: 8}
     6: {fechas: "2018-11-01", registros: 0}]
```

he intendado con esta funcion, pero no me sirve

```
result = result.sort(function (a, b) { 
  return convertirFecha(a.fechas) - convertirFecha(b.fechas); 
})
```

donde result es array que lo contiene,

te antemano mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Te anexo 2 funciones, una donde hacemos un `sort` y ordenamos el arreglo por fechas y otra donde evaluamos que no se repitan los registros, evaluamos que las 2 fechas sean iguales y además que tenga un valor de registros igual a 0:

```js
var fechaSort = [{
    fechas: "2018-10-26",
    registros: 0
}, {
    fechas: "2018-10-27",
    registros: 0
}, {
    fechas: "2018-10-28",
    registros: 0
}, {
    fechas: "2018-10-29",
    registros: 0
}, {
    fechas: "2018-10-30",
    registros: 0
}, {
    fechas: "2018-10-31",
    registros: 8
},{
    fechas: "2018-10-31",
    registros: 0
}, {
    fechas: "2018-11-01",
    registros: 0
}];

//Función para ordenar
fechaSort.sort((a,b) => (a.fechas > b.fechas) ? 1 : ((b.fechas > a.fechas) ? -1 : 0)); 

//Función para aplicar la condición, donde evaluamos si las fechas son iguales y además el registro es igual a 0
var fechaUnica = fechaSort.reduce(function(a,b){
      function indexOfProperty (a, b){
          for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
              if(a[i].fechas == b.fechas && b.registros == 0){
                   return i;
               }
          }
         return -1;
      }

      if (indexOfProperty(a,b) < 0 ) a.push(b);
        return a;
    },[]);

console.log(fechaUnica);
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona cuando las fechas tienen registros?

Comment: Si quieres que se valide una fecha repetida y además tiene cierta cantidad de registros sería modificar la condición de la segunda función, donde b.registros sea diferente de cero. Si te fue de utilidad te agradecería que marcaras como respuesta correcta. Saludos.

Comment: Ya le cambié la condición de la segunda función, y me muestra el objeto con los registros, pero se muestra repetido en caso del 31

Comment: Una disculpa, lo que comenté fue erróneo, debes cambiar toda la condición, ya que estás comparando a[i].fechas == b.fechas, si solo cambias b.registros == 0 no funcionará ya que estás tomando la otra comparación. Además que se debe modificar a lo que se le hace push según lo que deseas.